# Trouble setting up chartkick with flask

Tags: python, highcharts, flask, jinja2

I would like to use the python package [chartkick-0.4.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chartkick/0.4.0) to add graphs in my flask app. However, I am new to flask and having trouble setting it up. The `readme` file for the project states:

```
 Add chartkick to jinja_env and static_folder:

 app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=chartkick.js(),
 static_url_path='/static')
 app.jinja_env.add_extension("chartkick.ext.charts")
```

I have added chartstick.js to my templates/js folder. However, the line

```
app=Flask(__name__,static_folder=chartkick.js(), static_url_path='/static/js/')
```

throws a

```
NameError: "chartstic" is not defined.
```

What am I doing wrong ? How do i set up chartstick properly with flask?

This is my template:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src=""{{ url_for('static', filename='js/chartkick.js') }}"></script>
{% bar_chart data %}
```

UPDATE **** and this is my views file now:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import chartkick

app=Flask(__name__,static_folder=chartkick.js(), static_url_path='/static/js/')
app.jinja_env.add_extension("chartkick.ext.charts")


@app.route('/chart')
def first_graph():
    data = {'Chrome': 52.9, 'Opera': 1.6, 'Firefox': 27.7}
        return render_template('first_graph.html', data=data)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: i tried from chartkick import * but still the same error

Comment: Not `from chartkick import *`. Just import the name chartkick with `import chartkick`.

Comment: thank you. however it only displays a page with a "Loading...." text on it. I will edit my post with my template and view file

Comment: What errors do you have in JS console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is really simple. You have invalid HTML in this statement:

```
<script src=""{{ url_for('static', filename='js/chartkick.js') }}"></script>
```

Note the doubled left-side quotes. A secondary problem is that you have to specify the Javascript file without a path. The statement with these two errors fixed becomes:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='chartkick.js') }}"></script>
```

And now you should get your chart.

Note: the way their documentation tells you to set up your static path folder is awful. They are basically pointing the application's static folder to their own folder, which will prevent you from having any of your own static files. A much better way to handle this is to create a blueprint for chartkick and have the static folder for the blueprint point to their Javascript file.

Comment: thank you! it worked like a charm. they do not have scatter plots for python chartkick right? only the ones provided in the readme file

Comment: Looks like they only support line, pie column, bar and area charts at this time. Highchart does support scatter though, if you are willing to code it in Javascript directly.